# Python3 - grabbing data from dynamically refreshed table in webpage

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, python-requests

I am pulling some data from [this](http://www.canada.com/entertainment/television/tv-listings/index.html#f=grid) web page using the below back end call in Python. I have managed to get all the channels on the page returned by playing around with the `&items` parameter, however I cannot seem to grab the request in the console, or see any relevant params that will change the times of the day EPG data is populated for:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
        
url = 'http://tvmds.tvpassport.com/snippet/white_label/php/grid.php?subid=postmedia&lang=en&lu=36625D&tz=America%2FToronto&items=3100&st=&wd=940&nc=0&div=tvmds_frames&si=0'
                       
headers ={
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
}
                             
r = session.get(url, headers=headers)
status_code2 = r.status_code
                            
data2 = r.content.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')

filename = 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\mypath\\test_file.txt'
with open(filename, "a", encoding='utf-8', errors="ignore") as text_file:
    text_file.write(data2)
text_file.close
```

...all I get is an error in Google Chrome Dev Tools saying `[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript`.

Can anyone assist? I need to be able to grab program data from a full 24 hour period and across different days...

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand. The URL returns Json that contains HTML data. You can do `data = requests.get(url).json()` and then `df = pd.read_html(data['data'])[0]` or parse `data['data']` with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: no, you dont understand. it is the webpage itself i am having issues with. if you look at the output of the above, it only contains a limited number of timeslots. when i interactively change the timeslots being viewed in google chrome, the XHR requests appear to be being masked and i thus cannot see the params needed to amend my above request to grab different days/times...